# How to add another shell user to a amazon linux machine?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect via SSH to a new limited user account using PuTTY from a windows machine.  I created the user with `adduser limiteduser`, setup a password with `passwd limiteduser`, and copied a ssh key in that I created with puttygen. So far in WinSCP I can view the home directory and copy/remove files, but when I try to access the putty shell I get

```
Using username "limiteduser".
Server refused our key
```

And then a putty window popup that states `"Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)`

I can access the site with WinSCP and actually copy files over, so it appears the ssh authentication is working properly.

Do I need to do something else to allow the user to access the shell through putty?

Comment: Did you load the private key into putty?

Comment: That worked, maybe you want to answer the question so I can accept it.  How come entering the private key in WinSCP did not load it properly until I put it in putty directly?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you need to load the Private key into PuTTY.

Private keys are **purely** a client-side, and application-specific thing - the keys are not transferred to the server at any point, as you eluded to in your above comment. Each SSH client needs to know where to look for your private key, so it can be used in the authentication process. You should know that the private key should **never** leave the machine it was generated on. The private key **is** your identity, and should be protected. The public key, however, can be shared willy nilly, posted online, tattooed on your posterior, whatever.